# web service accessing wrapper

Tags: c#, web-services, timeout

hi i have to use a web service in my solution
I have a wrapper static class accessing web service as

```
public static class Authentication
{
    public static bool VerifyPassword(int membershipID, string password)
    {
        PCIValidationResult result = CreatePciWebService().ValidatePassword(
                 membershipID, password);            
        LoginValidationResult loginValidationResult =
            (LoginValidationResult)Enum.ToObject(
                 typeof(LoginValidationResult), result.ResultCode);         
        return true;
    }

    private static PCIWebService CreatePciWebService()
    {          
        PCIWebService service = new PCIWebService();
        service.Url = KioskManagerConfiguration.PciServiceUrl;
        return service;
    }
```

and I call this class in code 
like

```
Authentication.VerifyPassword(23,"testUser");
```

First call of code is succeed And after 2nd call the code
I got " the operation has timed out" after 2-3 min. waiting ...

How to call a web service ?

Comment: Did you mean to return something based on loginValidationResult, rather than true each time?

Comment: Hi marc ,first of all thanks for  your quick reply,the loginValidationResult is not the part of problem ,comes over the webService and checks the user status i'm ging to add code to control this buisness

Answer (score 1):

Apart from always returning true, and *possibly* using `using` (if the service is `IDisposable`), I can't see anything obviously wrong.

Have you tried tracing it with fiddler or wireshark to see what is happening at the transport level?

You could try adding `using`, but while this may tidy things up I'm not sure it will fix this issue:

```
using(PCIWebService svc = CreatePciWebService()) {
    PCIValidationResult result = svc.ValidatePassword(membershipID, password);
    //...etc
}
```